# Is it possible that the first derivatives of metric tensor vanish in a certain coordinate system?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am a student in physics department and I read in Weinberg's *Gravitation and Cosmology* that "at any point we can find a coordinate system in which the first derivatives of the metric tensor vanish", which he describes as an interpretation of the Equivalence Principle. But is it true in mathematics? If not, is there any counterexample? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates

Comment: Note that the first derivatives in normal coordinates vanish **at the centre** of the coordinates, not everywhere.

Comment: If you want to forgo the use of normal coordinates, here is a simple way to see this: https://deaneyang.github.io/blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/riemannian-geometry/2021/01/28/RiemannCurvature.html

Comment: If I may, I would like to translate @Deane's blog post in words my PhD advisor once told me: "There is no local geometric invariant in the first derivative of the coefficients of the metric".

Comment: @Didier, I like calling it the Hamilton trick, even though he wasn’t the first to use it, because he once said that he could never have done all the calculations in his Ricci flow papers without it.